# X11 Forwarding Problem Netscape

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, x11

I have the following problem.

A working verbose x11 forward request looks like this:

```
remote server release: Red Hat Linux release 6.2 (Zoot)

sh-4.1$  ssh -1 -vvv -l username -o "ForwardX11 yes" server.name netscape
OpenSSH_5.8p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to server.name [192.131.79.70] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/identity type 0
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.5, remote software version 1.2.26
debug1: no match: 1.2.26
debug1: Local version string SSH-1.5-OpenSSH_5.8
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Waiting for server public key.
debug1: Received server public key (768 bits) and host key (1024 bits).
debug1: Server host key: RSA1 0d:02:ad:64:5f:af:fa:e1:c6:ae:50:1a:91:7e:ab:f9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "server.name" from file "/home/shayre/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '1024'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA1 in file /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.131.79.70" from file "/home/shayre/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '1024'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA1 in file /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'proxy-bt-2' is known and matches the RSA1 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: Encryption type: 3des
debug1: Sent encrypted session key.
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: Installing crc compensation attack detector.
debug1: Received encrypted confirmation.
debug1: Trying RSA authentication with key '/home/username/.ssh/identity'
debug1: Received RSA challenge from server.
Enter passphrase for RSA key '/home/username/.ssh/identity': 
debug1: Sending response to host key RSA challenge.
debug1: Remote: RSA authentication accepted.
debug1: RSA authentication accepted by server.
Authenticated to server.name ([192.131.79.70]:22).
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth -f /tmp/ssh-aPHVuHic3976/xauthfile generat
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Sending command: netscape
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: fd 0 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Received X11 open request.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [X11 connection from server.name port 1874]
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
```

the non working output is as follows:

```
Red Hat Linux release 9 (Shrike)


$ ssh -1 -vvv -l username -o "ForwardX11 yes" server.address netscape
OpenSSH_5.8p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to server.address [192.65.220.98] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/identity type 0
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_3.7.1p2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_3.7.1p2 pat OpenSSH_3.*
debug1: Local version string SSH-1.5-OpenSSH_5.8
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Waiting for server public key.
debug1: Received server public key (768 bits) and host key (1024 bits).
debug1: Server host key: RSA1 53:40:10:d1:86:92:1e:d5:a1:70:0f:b0:4f:c8:67:eb
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "ext-proxy-2.ftel.co.uk" from file "/home/shayre/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '1024'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA1 in file /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.65.220.98" from file "/home/shayre/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '1024'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA1 in file /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'server.address' is known and matches the RSA1 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: Encryption type: 3des
debug1: Sent encrypted session key.
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
debug1: Installing crc compensation attack detector.
debug1: Received encrypted confirmation.
debug1: Trying RSA authentication with key '/home/username/.ssh/identity'
debug1: Received RSA challenge from server.
Enter passphrase for RSA key '/home/username/.ssh/identity': 
debug1: Sending response to host key RSA challenge.
debug1: Remote: RSA authentication accepted.
debug1: RSA authentication accepted by server.
Authenticated to server.address ([192.65.220.98]:22).
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth -f /tmp/ssh-kOywxfZB5752/xauthfile generate 127.0.0.1:0.0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 untrusted timeout 1200 2>/dev/null
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Sending command: netscape
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: fd 0 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
bash: line 1: netscape: command not found
Transferred: sent 1096, received 716 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 26095.4, received 17047.7
debug1: Exit status 127
```

I can see my client machine is forwarding x11 traffic and I am able to establish a normal ssh session ok, just when I request the netscape from this particular release it fails?

the working release Red Hat Linux release 6.2 (Zoot) gives me:

```
debug1: Received X11 open request.
```

the non-working release Red Hat Linux release 9 (Shrike) exits with:

```
bash: line 1: netscape: command not found
```

apart from the obvious is there another browser supported on this release, and how can I get this to work?

Comment: You seriously still have netscape installed on all your machines?  The 20th Century called, and they want their browser back.

Comment: haha not me mate work thing

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because it can't find a Netscape executable or wrapper script.  Install Netscape or try Firefox.

Comment: bash: line 1: Firefox: command not found - how do I find out what browser I can retrieve is there a command on remote server? thanks

Comment: Try opera and chrome.  If none of them work it may not have a graphical browser installed.

Comment: Previous script we used was and this used to give me a browser, can't quite remember which one though....

ssh -1 -f -l $LOGNAME -o "ForwardX11 yes" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -L 7011:1.1.1.1:22 proxy.server sleep 20 >/dev/null 2>&1 xterm -title ZEN -e ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -2 -l username -p 7011 -L 8080:remoteserver.name:8080 localhost &